# setOnTouchListener for record audio button does not work properly in Android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have the following method which starts recording the audio when the user holds the button clicked and stops the record when the user lifts his finger.

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private fun setTouchListenerForCreatingAudio() {
    // binding. recordAudioBtn is the button used for recording (I use data binding)
    binding.recordAudioBtn.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        when(event.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> startRecord()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> stopRecord()
        }
        false
    }
}
```

But I observed some strange behaviour. Sometimes the `ACTION_UP` case does not get triggered after lifting my finger so that `stopRecord()` is never called.

In some SO threads, I have read that one need to return `true` instead of `false` but testing it does not helped in my case.

Any suggestions ? Advice ?

Answer (score 0):

If the user's finger moves off the button before releasing, `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` will not be called. Instead, you will receive the `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` event (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#ACTION_CANCEL)). This may be the cause of the behaviour you see.

You should handle this case as well by either failing gracefully or executing the same ACTION_UP logic. You should also return true in the cases where you handle the event. For example:

```
return@setOnTouchListener when(event.action){
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
        startRecord()
        true
    }
    MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL,
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
        stopRecord()
        true
    } 
    else -> false
}
```